# How could I implement the mini player in Spotify for a web app in React JS or Angular

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angular, vue.js

Could somebody give me a hint or any kind of help in how to implement the mini player in Spotify for a web app in React JS, Angular, VueJs or just plane javascript.
[image]

[image]

I have no idea of how is this implemented so If if someone can give me just a tought or an approach to resolve this, I'll take it gladly.

Thank you!

Comment: Look into embeds: https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/embeds

You can start working from here.

Comment: I have my own web site that streams musics so I don't want a solution that implies Spotify. I want to do it from scratch in my own app.

Comment: The question is too broad. It's irrelevant to the frameworks. If you asked about how it works, it's https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Picture-in-Picture_API and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Picture-in-Picture_API